# qt5 and usblib in win7 (mingw32) linker produces undefined references to `_imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsA@16'

Tags: qt, libusb, libusb-1.0

I'm using `qt5.5` in linux and win7 (mingw32) ... in linux it works (i had to build new usblibs for compatibility reasons)

in windows using this library
`/usr/local/.../code-qt/libusb-1.0.19-rc1-win/MinGW32/static/`
i get the following errors and a few more, all with some

> **"_imp__SetupDixxxxxxx" being undefined**

since the libusb build in windows seems quite more complicated, i was unable to figure out how to do it

at this point i have no clue what is wrong and any help is highly appreciated

i have no problems rebuilding the lib with ming32w inside or outside of qt5 creator or any other way, but i would need to have a few steps described on how to proceed.

cheers EinHexenMeister

> E:\code-qt\qtHidTest\HidTest\windows\hid.c:289: error: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsA@16'
>
> E:\code-qt\qtHidTest\HidTest\windows\hid.c:298: error: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces@20'
>
> E:\code-qt\qtHidTest\HidTest\windows\hid.c:491: error: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4'
>
> E:\code-qt\qtHidTest\HidTest\windows\hid.c:313: error: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailA@24'
>
> E:\code-qt\qtHidTest\HidTest\windows\hid.c:347: error: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo@12'

Comment: is your lib path correct? It seems you need the `Setupapi.dll` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551015(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You need to link additional libraries for windows, add in your .pro file:

```
win32 {

LIBS += -lhid -lsetupapi

}
```

Comment: thank you very very much, this seem to have done it ... it linked and runs

i hope that this will also help others with qt and libusb on windows ... thanks again :)

Comment: @EinHexenMeister you should accept this answer to contribute to SO!